# In React Navigation, Remove one menu Item in DrawerNavigator

Tags: tabs, stack, react-navigation, drawer

I study React, React-Native, React-Navigation.... I have a some problem.

URL : https://snack.expo.io/rJgflVmCz

Keep the current menu flow, I want to remove AppStackNavigator Item in Drawer..

How can I get rid of it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZejj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are new to react native. If I'm wrong, then I apologize, here is a [Here is snack expo link](https://snack.expo.io/H1SQvjQ0z) with the AppStackNavigator out of the DrawerNavigator.
I did that by removing that screen from the DrawerNavigator method.